# Google chrome - does not open the link ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: apache, google-chrome, wamp, chromium, httpd.conf

In Google chrome i keep getting ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

[image]
[image]

Created certificate :

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048
C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key
C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl req -new -x509 -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 36500 -config C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin\openssl.cfg
```

What is wrong? Why getting ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917227/1427878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it WORKS.

[image]
[image]

## Step 1

A)

```
# openssl genrsa -out server_rootCA.key 2048
# openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key server_rootCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out server_rootCA.pem
```

B)

```
# cat server_rootCA.csr.cnf
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=BE
ST=oost-vlaanderen
L=Stackoverflow
O=Stackoverflow
OU=local_RootCA
emailAddress=helpdesk@Stackoverflow.com
CN = localhost

# cat v3.ext 
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

C)

```
# openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config <( cat server_rootCA.csr.cnf )

# openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA server_rootCA.pem -CAkey server_rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

## Step 2

Use in Apache

`SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key`

## Step 3:

- Add PEM to the browser
- Chromium -> Setting -> (Advanced) Manage Certificates -> Import -> 'server_rootCA.pem'

[image]

[image]
[image]